# Scraping data for Company details

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape Company name, Postcode, phone number and web address from:
https://www.matki.co.uk/matki-dealers/  Finding it difficult as the information is only retrieved upon clicking the region on the page. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated. Very new to both Python and especially scraping!

```
!pip install beautifulsoup4
!pip install urllib3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://www.matki.co.uk/matki-dealers/"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanted to do: (you can put the result after in a file or a database, or even parse it and use it directly)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.matki.co.uk/matki-dealers/"
page = requests.get(URL)

# parse HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# extract the HTML results
results = soup.find(class_="dealer-region")
company_elements = results.find_all("article")

# Loop through the results and extract the wanted informations
for company_element in company_elements:
    # some cleanup before printing the info:
    company_info = company_element.getText(separator=u', ').replace('Find out more »', '')

    # the results ..
    print(company_info)
```

Output:

```
ESP Bathrooms & Interiors, Queens Retail Park, Queens Street, Preston, PR1 4HZ, 01772 200400, www.espbathrooms.co.uk
Paul Scarr & Son Ltd, Supreme Centre, Haws Hill, Lancaster Road A6, Carnforth, LA5 9DG, 01524 733788, 
Stonebridge Interiors, 19 Main Street, Ponteland, NE20 9NH, 01661 520251, www.stonebridgeinteriors.com 
Bathe Distinctive Bathrooms, 55 Pottery Road, Wigan, WN3 5AA, www.bathe-showroom.co.uk
Draw A Bath Ltd, 68 Telegraph Road, Heswall, Wirral, CH60 7SG, 0151 342 7100, www.drawabath.co.uk
Acaelia Home Design, Unit 4 Fence Avenue Industrial Estate, Macclesfield, Cheshire, SK10 1LT, 01625 464955, www.acaeliahomedesign.co.uk
...
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks so much - I amended 'customer-region' to 'customer-overview' to pull every region. I really appreciate your help. When trying to export to CSV using to_csv, I meet the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'. I've searched far and wide but can't figure a solution. Help figuring this out would be amazing.

Comment: yeah it is normal because you're trying to save a string with a method it doesn't have, try putting all the company info in a list and changing it to a df using `pandas` library or simply write each string in a file using basic read/write file methods.